# LDIF Parser (C#)

Tags: c#, ldif

I am looking for an LDIF parser for C#. I am trying to parse an LDIF file so that I can check objects don't exist before adding them. Adding them when the already exist using ntdsSchemaAdd) causes an entry in the error logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick websearch revealed: http://wiki.github.com/skradel/Zetetic.Ldap/. They have provided a .net API.

From the page:

> Zetetic.Ldap is a .NET library for
>   .NET 2 and above, which makes it
>   easier to work with directory servers
>   (like Active Directory, ADAM, Red Hat
>   Directory Server, and others). Some of
>   the key features of Zetetic.Ldap are:
>
> 1.LDIF file parsing and generation – Read and write the file format used
>   for moving data around between
>   directory systems
>
> 2.LDAP Entry-oriented API with change tracking – Create and modify directory
>   objects in a more natural way
>
> 3.LDAP Schema interrogation – Quick programmatic access to the kinds of
>   objects and fields your directory
>   server understands. Learn if an
>   attribute is a string, a number, a
>   date, etc., without lots of manual
>   research and re-parsing
>
> 4.LDIF Pivoter – Turn an LDIF file into a (comma or tab-delimited) flat
>   file for analysis or loading into
>   systems that don’t speak LDIF We built
>   the Zetetic.Ldap library to make
>   directory projects and programming
>   faster and easier, and release it here
>   in the hopes that others will find it
>   useful too. As far as we know, this is
>   the only .NET library that really
>   understands the LDIF specification.

Download link: http://github.com/downloads/skradel/Zetetic.Ldap/Zetetic.Ldap_20090831.zip

Answer (score 1):

I would parse it myself.

If you look at the [LDIF RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) for the EBNF, you'll see that it's not a very complex grammar.

I've parsed a large amount of LDIF before using Regexes reliably.  Though your mileage may vary.

Comment: Writing a parser will always take quite a bit of time to get all of the details right, especially if you implement the complete spec. If you only do a partial implementation, then this will cause all kinds of problems later on.