# How to read a LDF file?

Tags: c#, linq

```
dn: CN=FirstName LastName,OU=IT Group,OU=Resources,OU=CompanySite,DC=example,DC=com
changetype: add
accountExpires: 0
businessCategory: iDQC
c: US
cn: FirstName LastName
co: United States
codePage: 0
company: CompanySite
countryCode: 840
department: Information Technology
description: 2/24/2015 10:39:25 AM firstname.lastname logged on to COMPUTERNAME
displayName: FirstName LastName
distinguishedName: 
 CN=FirstName LastName,OU=IT Group,OU=CompanySite,DC=example,DC=com
division: N/A
dSCorePropagationData: 20160511184301.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20160222194509.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20150710200320.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20140926143022.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 16010714223649.0Z
.... (hundreds of lines here)
```

I have a LDF file that looks like this.

I want to retrieve the following fields

```
department
telephoneNumber
title
```

Is there a better way to do this than read each row by row?

Comment: there is no magic here. YOu want to find some lines in a text file, you gotta scan through it

Comment: I want multiple lines. Can Linq help here?

Comment: Are their multiple changes in this LDF or is it one LDF per DN?  It is possible to write a parser with LINQ but it's not a simple task.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2849

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LDIF Parser (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270334/ldif-parser-c)

Comment: @MatthewWhited just reading the data. Not writing it.

Comment: That's okay, but LDIF is still a hierarchal data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foundLines = File.ReadLines(<ldif file>)
  .Where(l=>l.StartsWith("department") || l.StartsWith("title") || l.StartsWith("telephoneNumber"));
```

is a good start, but its not magic, its just reading all the lines of the file.